# Pandas resample().apply() with custom function very slow

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply, resample

I have a pandas Series in business-day frequency, and I want to resample it to weekly frequency where I take the product of those 5 days in a week.

Some dummy data:

```
dates = pd.bdate_range('2000-01-01', '2022-12-31')
s = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(size=len(dates)), index=dates)

# randomly assign NaN's
mask = np.random.randint(0, len(dates), round(len(dates)*.9))
s.iloc[mask] = np.nan
```

Notice that majority of this Series are NaN's.

The simple `.prod` method called after `.resample` is fast:

```
%timeit s.resample('W-FRI').prod()
10.2 ms ± 500 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

But I have to be very precise when taking the product in that I want to give `min_count=1` when calling `np.prod`, and that's when it becomes very slow:

```
%timeit s.resample('W-FRI').apply(lambda x: x.prod(min_count=1))
69.1 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I think the problem is not specific to `np.prod` but can be generalized to comparing all pandas-recognizable functions vs. applying custom functions.

How do I achieve a similar performance as `.resample().prod()` with `min_count=1` argument?

Comment: `apply` is known to be slow, since it has to iterate at python level.  The exceptions are (based on some other SO), when the function is a 'builtin pandas', or you can use the 'raw' mode, which does the work in `numpy`.

Comment: [`.resample().prod(min_count=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html). See [implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VCg2.png)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I feel embarassed that I shall have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Until I saw Trenton McKinney's comment, I was going to propose:

```py
def f(rs, min_count=0):
    res = rs.prod()
    res[rs.count() < min_count] = np.nan
    return res

%timeit f(s.resample('W-FRI'), min_count=1)
# same timing as s.resample('W-FRI').prod()
```

But Trenton's suggestion is far better:

```
s.resample('W-FRI').prod(min_count=1)
```

I'm only mentioning this for other cases when one would be tempted to use `.apply()`, but where using the resampling object a couple of times with builtin numpy functions is faster.